# Transparent Window in .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0

is there any way that winforms or WPF can do this kind of UI? transparent with blur window.

[image]

Comment: Just a hint: your question is not about C#, but about .NET. Which version?

Comment: [There is](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell/), and this has been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forenote: Windows 8 removes the Aero Glass effect. Windows will appear with a solid background where there would be glass (like how they appear on Windows 7 when you disable the glass effect but still run the DWM).

That said, the effect is done using Win32's `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function. Using this in your program differs depending on whether you're using WPF or WinForms (as WPF windows do some pretty interesting window subclassing, and of course, WPF controls are largely windowless).

To get a "whole glass" window, you just use the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function to fill your window, rather than just the first 50px or so, which is what IE and other browsers do.

This is the canonical MSDN article on how to do this with WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx

For WinForms, see this blog article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx

Enjoy, but not for long considering Windows 8...

Comment: There is a way to enable glass in Windows 8 though isn't there?

Comment: @series0ne No, there is not. The assets in Windows' theme files that define the glass effect have been removed completely. As far as I know it is not possible.

Comment: So is this article a hack? http://www.askvg.com/hidden-secret-trick-to-enable-activate-aero-glass-in-windows-8-aero-lite-theme/

Comment: @series0ne that article describes a feature present in the Windows 8 Beta/Preview that was removed from RTM. Also it only enables transparency, it does not apply the blur effect or the glass "shimmer" layer.

Comment: Sigh! Windows 8 Sucks!